# Dropdown List SelectedItems Postback Not there

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not sure what to do here, I might have to use viewstates, but I need help.

I have a dropdown list, I am not databinding. I would know if I was I should do a `Page.IsPostBack` and not databind.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWeeklyWeightIn" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Now in my code behind I have this:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string wwin = "";
        wwin = ddlWeeklyWeightIn.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
```

On the button click is always "1", never the selected item.

Thank you

Comment: `DropDownList` class has a property called `SelectedItem`?

Comment: have you enabled viewstate on the dropdownlist?

Comment: yes enabled viewstate

Comment: I make a page like that and work to me. Look if you make any server redirect, or reset, or any other that breaks thats.

Comment: It works fine with your code. Just create a sample application and try. it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aspx side:
add autopostback=true to dropdown property and and use listitem as following:
ListItem Text="4" Value="4"> etc

**Code Behind:** string wwin = ""; wwin = ddlWeeklyWeightIn.SelectedValue;

Answer (score 0):

try adding EnableViewState="True" to your dropdown control.

Comment: When the list is render on the page like that the `EnableViewState` is not affect it.

Answer (score 0):

A post back is causing to reset your selected value. either use `if(!IsPostBack)` or use update panel to prevent post back.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to make sure but could you try using:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWeeklyWeightIn" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="4"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Could you check you don't just SET the selected item during page's initialization?

Comment: I deleted the page and recreated it with a new control. It worked then, I still have no clue what the problem was, or any other way to fix it.